# Java using interface as a callback

Tags: java, interface, callback

I am trying to implement a callback procedure by having a class implement and interface, and then pass that class as an object (of the interface) to another class. However, I am receiving the error: "The constructor ClassB(TestMe) is undefined". I thought that I was doing this correctly, I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can someone please offer some advice? My code is below:

I have an interface:

```
public interface RequestResults {

     public void requestFailed(String message);

     public void requestSucceeded(String xml);

}
```

And I have a class that implements the interface:

```
public class TestMe implements RequestResults {

    public TestMe() {

        ClassB b = new ClassB(this);

    }

    public void requestFailed(String message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void requestSucceeded(String xml) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Finally, I have a class that is instantiated in the prior class:

```
  public class ClassB {

    RequestResults results;

    public ClassB(RequestResults results) {

        this.results = results;

    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding.  Looks fine to me.

Comment: Where do you receive that error message? Your code compiled fine.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned this, but I am developing for the android...also eclipse is giving me that error inline

Comment: it does not matter android or not, the code is fine. Run a clean on your project and recompile

Comment: Side note: I hope this is just a case of a simplified example, but passing `this` to another object while in the constructor is not a good practice. It's possible that the object will only be partially created when other code tries to call it.

Comment: @behrk2, eclipse has a clean feature specifically in case something happens that causes it's model to be inconsistent with the saved code in the editor. Click "project > clean..." and clean your projects. This will delete all the compiled binaries and force eclipse to completely recompile your project.

Comment: Hey all, I did a clean and I am still receiving the notice. Really weird. I know that it should not matter, but I'm developing for Android 2.1 update 1. I am using JRE 1.6.0_16. I'm really perplexed as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've coded the whole thing on my side and everything compiled. Cleaning and compiling it afresh might help.

Answer (score 4):

I think your code is correct. Try to compile everything again. Maybe you have been using an old version of `TestMe`.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm. compiles just fine for me. Here is an [ideone SSCCE](http://ideone.com/V3R34).

Answer (score 1):

Also Compiled for me....
You must clean your project in eclipse it happens sometimes